# variable target in a makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to compile set of targets. However it only seems to do the first one. Below is a cut down of the my makefile that shows the error.

```
  OBJECTS = abc def ghi
  SOURCES = abc.c def.c ghi.c

  $(OBJECTS):     $(SOURCES)
          @echo target is $@, source is $<
```

In shell,

```
  $ touch abc.c def.c ghi.c
  $ make
```

When I run make I get the following output:

```
  target is abc, source is abc.c
```

So it only seems to be running the first target.

If I replace $< with $^, the output is:

```
  target is abc, source is abc.c def.c ghi.c
```

**My question, is it possible to perform expansions on variables like with the (%: %) pattern?**

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try this:

```
  OBJECTS = abc def ghi

  all: $(OBJECTS)

  $(OBJECTS):%:%.c
          @echo target is $@, source is $<
```

The trouble was

1. The default target (which is what Make chooses if you just type `make`) is the first target in the makefile, which was `abc`.

   You made *all* sources prerequisites of *every* object. That is, all three sources were prerequisites of `abc`. They were also prerequisites of `def` and of `ghi`.

Comment: Running `make` with no arguments still only executes the first target (`abc`).

Comment: @Gingi: Is that the result you get? What version of Make are you using?

Comment: @Beta GNU Make 3.81, Mac OS X 10.8.4

Comment: @Gingi: That's strange... what if you add a command to the `all` rule: `@echo all preqs are $^`, what does it say?

Comment: Thanks, this works for my particular problem. Here's a shot (after four years) but what does $(OBJECTS):%:%.c mean? I read: for any given object, take the equivalent .c file as a prerequisite. But what does the additional %: mean? Hope you can help!

Comment: @Nebula: Static pattern rules are described [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern). The rule does not assume that Make knows what the equivalent .c file is, it is more general. It says: for any target in this list (`$(OBJECTS)`), take the entire target name (`%`), and add ".c" (`%.c`) to get the prerequisite.

Comment: Hi @Beta, thanks a bunch! That explains it very well. My life is more complete now =p

Comment: Here's a question: how do you go the other way?  For instance if you had a bunch of zip files you wanted to create so "OBJECTS=f1.zip f2.zip f3.zip" and you wanted your dependency to be "f1 f2 f3" etc.  I tried something like "$(ZIPS):%:$(ZIPS:.zip=)" but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @KellyBeard: No problem, `$(ZIPS):%.zip:%`